# What is the exact purpose of function addMaxValueCheck () of RoundedTextArea in GWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, gwt

```
comments = new RoundedTextArea();
comments.addMaxValueCheck(500);
```

Comment: Please add details to show your research, and properly format the question (don't put whole questions inside the title).

Comment: which package does RoundedTextArea belong to? I have never seen or heard of this class.

Answer (score 0):

The object **RoundedTextArea**, is not a current GWT object.

Check the Javadoc for GWT here: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/

You must be using some other type of SDK, API, or locally developed code and thinking it's GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Only my guess : counts the number of character entered into the text area and gives you a warning  / alert when reaching 500 char.

As mentionned above RoundedTextArea is not part of GWT